# Get element by type AND field using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with a div element that has a generic class with no ID (so I can't use select getElementById or getElementByClass) and I'm trying to select the element by **type** and **field** from the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" type="enum" field="status_c" colspan="3">Firm</div>
```

Is this even doable?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelector):

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div[type="enum"][field="status_c"]');

console.log(el.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12" type="enum" field="status_c" colspan="3">Firm</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" type="enum" field="status_d" colspan="3">Not Firm</div>
```